# Get filtered fields from RestApi response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I need to get filtered response of RestApi.
For example, I want to get "id", "name" and   "coordinates" fields from the response.

```
fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error fetching', error)
    });
```

I do not know how can I do it?

```
[
   {
      "id":22,
      "visible":true,
      "name":"Distance",
      "note":"",
      "color":"#1979E4",
      "point_of_view":{
         "image_id":2961484116667333,
         "scs_orientation":null,
         "fov":null,
         "scs_location":[
            10.069071420248019,
            -3.4315537915724224,
            1.1707962178213307
         ]
      },
      "type":"DISTANCE_VERTICAL_MEASUREMENT",
      "scs_geometry":{
         "type":"LineString",
         "coordinates":[
            [
               4.592703919368196,
               -4.053005766962444,
               -0.9250943789482116
            ],
            [
               4.592703919368196,
               -4.053005766962444,
               9.206785308182239
            ]
         ]
      },
      "created_date":1651137546590,
      "measurement_group":6
   },
   {
      "id":23,
      "visible":true,
      "name":"Distance",
      "note":"",
      "color":"#1979E4",
      "point_of_view":{
         "image_id":2961484116667333,
         "scs_orientation":null,
         "fov":null,
         "scs_location":[
            10.069071420248019,
            -3.4315537915724224,
            1.1707962178213307
         ]
      },
      "type":"DISTANCE_HORIZONTAL_MEASUREMENT",
      "scs_geometry":{
         "type":"LineString",
         "coordinates":[
            [
               12.092187102599642,
               -6.594044278306256,
               -0.9200943837165831
            ],
            [
               12.941293176077313,
               -2.77877760536178,
               -0.9200943837165831
            ]
         ]
      },
      "created_date":1651137602618,
      "measurement_group":6
   }
]
```

Comment: You can `map` over the response and grab they keys you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

It's basic programming. Just map you array and pick up needed fields

```js
// URL to api
const url: string = "some url"

// Request options
const options: RequestInit = {
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
}

// Request
fetch(url, options)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
      // Check that response data is array
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        // Construct new array with items 
        return data.map(item => {
            return {
                id: item?.id,
                name: item?.name,
                coordinates: item?.scs_geometry?.coordinates
            }   
        })
    } else {
        // Throw error because of bad data
        throw new Error('bad data')
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Catch both response errors and our error
    console.log("error fetching", error);
  })

// Async version of same request
const makeRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options)
        const data = await response.json()

        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
            // Construct new array with items 
            return data.map(item => {
                return {
                    id: item?.id,
                    name: item?.name,
                    coordinates: item?.scs_geometry?.coordinates
                }   
            })
        } else {
            // Throw error because of bad data
            throw new Error('bad data')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error fetching", error)
    }

    return null
}

makeRequest()
```

Comment: Getting error, not all code paths return a value

Comment: @Shahgee, I fixed. But it is additional ts checks, I don't care

Comment: @Shahgee `makeRequest().then(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: It enters in loop   if (Array.isArray(data)) { console.log("it is arrayof length:" + data.length);}, and shows it is arrayof length:8 , but then makeRequest().then(x => console.log(x)) returns  "undefined".